# VS 2019 - ASP.NET Core MVC web app (written in C#) : multiple errors on brand new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Brand new project utilizing ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC, and written in C#.

I'm getting multiple errors inside the Error List window when viewing any of the default .cshtml pages.

However, the project still builds and runs normally.

Errors include:

```
- The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context.
- The name 'RenderBody' does not exist in the current context.
- The name 'await' does not exist in the current context.
- The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context.
- The namespace "ASP" already contains a definition for '_Page_Default_cshtml'
```

(For full list https://pastebin.com/YM5JnqBj)

Comment: A few things come to mind: broken VS installation (you can repair through Visual Studio Installer), bad cache files and possibly some other stuff. Can you try to close VS, go to the project folder in your file explorer and delete entirely the folders `bin` and `obj`? Hopefully it's that simple

Comment: how did you exactly create the project?

Comment: Also, that's not a .NET 5 application, that's an ASP.NET Framework app. ASP.NET Core apps do not use the `System.Web` namespace

Comment: Hi Camilo, are you saying I'm utilizing the wrong Framework? What should I be using?
Edit: Deleting bin and obj did nothing unfortunately. Working on repairing now and will let you know.

Comment: We need to know how you created the project, as @DanielA.White asked before. You say ".NET 5" but the errors say otherwise

Comment: Camilo, I created a GIF that shows the process I go through hope it helps.
https://i.imgur.com/rKY4XiR.gif

Comment: @Wehrum Oh my that's weird... and bad... I'd tell you to reinstall VS, something very wrong is going on there. Never seen such thing. It *looks like* something is adding code referencing `System.Web` assemblies, but that doesn't happen on a brand new installation

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thank you for confirming. I'm going to attempt the repair and if that doesn't work will do a full re-install. I honestly thought I was doing something wrong, didn't even think of reinstalling/repairing. Will provide an update if I get it working. :)
Edit: Repair worked! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I got it working after the repair, if you want to post your answer as it was definitely some kind of corrupted installation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you did not choose ASP.NET and .NET Cross-Platform Development when installing VS 2019. Only other environments were selected for development. I created my ASP.NET project without installing the correct modules. After noticing this, I went back and installed the two missing modules, but this did not solve the problem. Some links on the back end of VS 2019 are not established.

The final solution-reinstall VS 2019 with the correct modules from the beginning (without trying to fix it first). Now all assistants, the code is complete, Intellicode, everything is normal.

ERROR：
[image]

Comment: Corrupted installation of Visual Studio 2019 was causing the errors. A repair of the installation using Visual Studio installer fixed the issue. It may have been that at the time I did not select those at the initial install and the repair added them automatically. Regardless, thank you.